# How to run JavaScript from local files in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, client, local

I have encountered this problem of JavaScript not running from local files when testing a website.
I am in great despair and need your help.
I have linked the JS correctly and everything, but it's just not working.
All settings are correctly enabled in Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the URL bar says in Chrome, and what the `src` attributes of your Javascript files are when this issue occurs.

Comment: probably an XSS issue

Answer (score 0):

Any problem caused by web browsers treating local files different to network files is best solved by installing a web server (there are many free options) on your development machine (optionally inside a VM) and testing through that.

This deals with many different issues include ones related to cross-origin security and relative URIs.